# UDP "sendto" outside the local network

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp, sendto

Hi I started programming UDP sockets recently and I've been using them for all kinds of stuff on a local network. but I cannot seem to find anything about how to send a UDP packet outside my lovely firewall.

Here's the code i use for binding UDP sockets

```
int handle = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP );
sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
address.sin_port = htons( (unsigned short) /* port */);
bind( handle, (const sockaddr*) &address, sizeof(sockaddr_in) )
```

and here's the code i use for sending a packet

```
sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( /*local network IP Address*/ );
address.sin_port = htons( (unsigned short) /* port */ );

sendto( handle, (const char*)/* packet data */, size, 0, (sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(sockaddr_in) );
```

And finally here's the code I use for receiving packets

```
sockaddr_in from;
socklen_t fromLength = sizeof( from );

int received_bytes = recvfrom( handle, (char*)data, size, 0, (sockaddr*)&from, &fromLength );
```

Comment: Most likely, the problem is a firewall at the *server* side. Does UDP traffic using [`netcat`](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) work fine? If not, first fix the firewalls (on a home router, you have to configure port forwarding at the server side, or even employ an elaborate [NAT traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) scheme in your application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since UDP is a "not connected" way of sending data you have to add rules to your router's firewall so that it routes the port (to the computer that is supposed to receive the data).

The problem doesn't come from the code, but from the network infrastructure.

Comment: You don't have to provide an ISP IP or anything to find the local network with the receiver on?

Comment: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/faq.html This page has a small section on if you are behind a firewall, that helped answer my question.